Ubuntu gives only manual installation option
I am new to Linux and trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop alongside Windows 10. It only shows the manual partitioning option which requires me to partition the disk which I don't know how to do properly. I'm unable to follow tutorials probably because they were written years ago.
Manual partitioning screen of the Ubuntu 24.04 installer:

I need help on how to get Ubuntu to let me install it alongside Windows or just delete Windows and install Ubuntu. (It's a new Windows with literally nothing).
I want to add that I am installing Ubuntu using UNetbootin as described here (How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?) and not with a bootable USB.
Bitlocker is disabled, but the issue persists.

Did you shrink the Windows partition and create free and "unformatted" space from within Windows, for Ubuntu to find? Try disabling "Fast Startup" in Windows. Then try to install Ubuntu again.

I am afraid we will need a screenshot of the partition table.

user68186 no I did not shrink windows or create a free and unformatted space from within windows and I do not know how to do that. I have disabled fast startup and bitlocker is off but still the same issue

mikewhatever, I have edited the post to add an image of the partition as seen as I try installing Ubuntu. Is that what you requested or should I follow this procedure below?https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/how-to-view-partitions.html

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think it is more reliable to make a USB boot drive with Ubuntu and boot from that drive. See this link and follow its steps (the 3rd step shows how to create a bootable USB stick and the 4th step how to boot from it). If problems with Etcher (as described in the step), you can try Rufus.

you are showing the old BIOS with MBR(msdos) partitioning. Since 2012 Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning for Windows 8. So your Windows 10 is either an upgrade from older Windows 7 or not installed per Microsoft recommendations. BIOS mode was only for old systems that did not have UEFI. If hardware that old, then light weight flavor will work much better as Ubuntu is for newer systems.  Also if system is UEFI capable be sure to install in same boot mode BIOS or UEFI as Windows install or backup & reinstall Windows in UEFI mode.

https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)  I have also installed Kubuntu which is more of a mid-weight flavor on older systems as well as my newer systems.
